# How to add an element to select field in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I am building a form in Symfony 2 using this code:

```
class EntradasSalidasNoMarcadasType extends AbstractType {

     public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
         ->add('idfunc','text')
         ->add('digito','text')
          ->add('idempresa', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'Desytec\biotempoBundle\Entity\Empresa',
                    'property' => 'nombre',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
                        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
                                ->where('a.deleted IS NULL AND a.deletedby IS NULL')
                                ->add('orderBy', 'a.idEmpresa ASC');
                    }
                ))
            ->add('iddepto', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'Desytec\biotempoBundle\Entity\Departamento',
                    'property' => 'nombredepto',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
                        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
                                ->where('a.deleted IS NULL AND a.deletedby IS NULL')
                                ->add('orderBy', 'a.nombredepto ASC');
                    }
                ))
         ->add('fecha','date', array('format' => 'MMMM - yyyy','widget' => 'choice','years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y') - 100)));
    }
}
```

Look at the widget called "iddepto". Combobox content comes from database.

Now I need to add an "All" option at the begining of the combobox.

I have not found any way to do this simple thing.

In indexAction of the controller I have this code:

```
$form   = $this->createForm(new EntradasSalidasNoMarcadasType());
```

And finally, this is the view:

```
{{ form_widget(form.iddepto, { 'attr': {'class': 'input-text'} }) }}
```

Regards
Jaime

Comment: If a user select all option , what should happen then ?

Comment: since "All" isn't really an entity, this might be a bit complicated, since the field is not multiple, apparently.

Comment: Never mind... By seeing the twig definition for the combobox, I saw that  form_widget accepts a parameter to add the empty option specifying a display name.